# jQuery dialog won't switch to modal after initialization

Tags: jquery-ui, modal-dialog, jquery-ui-dialog

If I initialize my modal like this:

```
$("#dlg").dialog({
    open: function (e) {
        $(this).load('mvc action url');
    },
    close: function () {
        $(this).dialog('destroy').empty();
    },
    modal: true
});
```

...it initializes as modal.  However, if I leave out `modal: true` at initialization and try to set modality after the dialog is already open like this:

```
$("#dlg").dialog("option", "modal", true);
```

...it doesn't work.  I know it's being set because I can alert the modal value after setting it.  I'm also properly referencing jquery-ui's library because I can open it as modal at initialization.

**Edit**

Here's a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/s9zmfkdn/1/

When you click open initially, it shows as modal as expected.  Now remove the line as I instruct in the fiddle.  When you open the dialog this time and then click *Make it modal*, nothing happens

Comment: But you destroy the object when it's closed?? You need to re-initialize it before calling `option` on it again. Check your console, I bet you have an error sitting there.

Comment: @Twisty No, I am executing my other script while the dialog is currently open, so it hasn't been destroyed at this point.

Comment: Could you update your example to be more clear.

Comment: @Twisty See update for fiddle

Answer (score 0):

So there are a few things that are causing this to fail to work as you anticipated.

1. You wrapped the initialization of the dialog in a function, so it was not globally available to other functions.
2. You destroy the dialog upon close, so it no longer exists to allow the change of the `modal` option.

It's not clear why you're doing it this way and I suspect there is something you're not sharing. Regardless, here is one example that works:

http://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/s9zmfkdn/2/

**HTML**

```
<div id="basesystem" title="whatever" style="display:none"></div>
<input type="button" class="moduleloader" value="Open" />

<input id="makemodal" type="button" value="Remove Modal" />
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  $("#basesystem").dialog({
    open: function(e) {
      $(this).html('<span>hello</span>');
    },
    close: function() {
      $(this).empty();
    },
    modal: true,
    autoOpen: false
  });

  $("#makemodal").click(function() {
    if ($("#basesystem").dialog("option", "modal")) {
      $("#basesystem").dialog("option", "modal", false);
      $(this).val("Make Modal");
    } else {
      $("#basesystem").dialog("option", "modal", true);
      $(this).val("Remove Modal");
    }
  });

  $(".moduleloader").click(function() {
    $("#basesystem").dialog("open");
  });
});
```

Now if you need, you can define the object more globally and manipulate it like so:

http://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/s9zmfkdn/4/

**HTML**

```
<div id="basesystem" title="whatever" style="display:none"></div>
<input type="button" class="moduleloader" value="Open" />

<input id="makemodal" type="button" value="Remove Modal" data-modal="true" />
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  var $diag = $("#basesystem");
  $(".moduleloader").click(function() {
    $diag.dialog({
      open: function(e) {
        $diag.html('<span>hello</span>');
      },
      close: function() {
        $diag.dialog("destroy").empty();
      },
      modal: $("#makemodal").data("modal")
    });
  });

  $("#makemodal").click(function() {
    if ($(this).data("modal")) {
      $(this).data("modal", false);
      $(this).val("Make Modal");
    } else {
      $(this).data("modal", true);
      $(this).val("Remove Modal");
    }
  });
});
```

This creates a new dialog every time and destroys it upon close. The only difference is that `modal` preference is stored someplace. You could also do this by storing it in global variable too.

**Update 1**

Based on your description, what you'll want to do is remove or create the `ui-widget-overlay` element.

Try this on for size: http://jsfiddle.net/s9zmfkdn/5/

```
$(function() {
  function removeOverlay() {
    $(".ui-widget-overlay").remove();
  }

  function setOverlay() {
    if ($(".ui-widget-overlay").length) {
      return false;
    }
    var $ov = $("<div>", {
      class: "ui-widget-overlay"
    }).css({
      width: $(window).width(),
      height: $(window).height(),
      zIndex: 1001
    });
    $("body").append($ov);
  }

  $("#basesystem").dialog({
    open: function(e) {
      $(this).html('<span>hello</span>');
      var $button = $("<a>", {
        href: "#"
      }).html("Toggle Modal").button().click(function() {
        if ($(".ui-widget-overlay").length) {
          removeOverlay();
        } else {
          setOverlay();
        }
      }).appendTo($(this));
    },
    close: function() {
      $(this).empty();
    },
    modal: true,
    autoOpen: false
  });

  $("#makemodal").click(function() {
    if ($("#basesystem").dialog("option", "modal")) {
      $("#basesystem").dialog("option", "modal", false);
      $(this).val("Make Modal");
    } else {
      $("#basesystem").dialog("option", "modal", true);
      $(this).val("Remove Modal");
    }
  });

  $(".moduleloader").click(function() {
    $("#basesystem").dialog("open");
  });
});
```

Comment: The idea is that I have an ASP.NET MVC Detail view loaded into a dialog.  When I click an edit button, it loads the Edit view HTML directly into the DIV using $("#dlg").load("action url here").  After I click edit, I want the non-modal dialog to change to modal while the dialog is still open (ie, I don't want to close it and reopen it)

Comment: More info:  Why I want to change to modal while it's still open is because I have other dialogs open at the same time with other views loaded into them.  Setting modality after a dialog has entered edit mode will help ensure that only one of these dialogs can be in edit mode at once.

Comment: Just now getting back to this.  Seemed to work at first, but it appears to have z-index issues when there are multiple modals open at once.  The overlay appears, but it's behind all windows.  I need to to appear behind only the top-level dialog.  Working on updating my fiddle.  Might have it tomorrow unless you can reproduce my issue in a pinch

Comment: @oscilatingcretin think of the z-index like layers. Also remember that dialogs were not really designed to be used in this fashion. You may end up needing to set the z-index of each dialog and associated modal overlay manually as you open more dialogs "on top" of each other. 1001, 1002, 1003 etc